# Typography Material UI not found

Tags: reactjs

The Material UI library doesn't respond in case when typography is separately installed in the project libraries.
The project isn't compiling and giving this error

```
./src/App.js
```

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Typography' in 'C:\Users\Sara Durrani\react\screenstask\src'

Comment: npm install typeface-roboto --save Tried with this command

Comment: How do you import it?

Comment: import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. Apparently now you have to import it from **core**:

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have import Typography like this:

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
```